# There is an issue in react-native-paper SegmentedButtons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, button, react-hooks

> I am using **react-native-paper** for **SegmentedButtons** this is the
> website link of react-native-paper.

[react-native-paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/segmented-buttons.html)

> I just copy and paste all the code in my Project but It gives me this
> error

> **Error:** Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

> when **I remove the code of segmentButton then it works fine** but when
> add the code in my project it always gives me this error.
> when I run this code in Expo snack then it didn't gives any kind of error and runs fine
> I just cop

[Expo snack Link](https://snack.expo.dev/@muhammadabdullahrishi/1ce738?name=SegmentedButtons&description=https%3A%2F%2Fcallstack.github.io%2Freact-native-paper%2Fsegmented-buttons.html&code=import%20*%20as%20React%20from%20%27react%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20SafeAreaView%2C%20StyleSheet%20%7D%20from%20%27react-native%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20SegmentedButtons%20%7D%20from%20%27react-native-paper%27%3B%0A%0Aconst%20MyComponent%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20%5Bvalue%2C%20setValue%5D%20%3D%20React.useState(%27%27)%3B%0A%0A%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%3CSafeAreaView%20style%3D%7Bstyles.container%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CSegmentedButtons%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3D%7Bvalue%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onValueChange%3D%7BsetValue%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20buttons%3D%7B%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20%27walk%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3A%20%27Walking%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20%27train%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3A%20%27Transit%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20value%3A%20%27drive%27%2C%20label%3A%20%27Driving%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FSafeAreaView%3E%0A%20%20)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20styles%20%3D%20StyleSheet.create(%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20flex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20alignItems%3A%20%27center%27%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20MyComponent%3B&dependencies=react-native-paper,@expo/vector-icons%40%5E13.0.0,react-native-safe-area-context)

**my Code**

```
    import {SegmentedButtons} from 'react-native-paper';
    
      const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    
return (
     <SafeAreaView>
            <SegmentedButtons
               value={value}
    onValueChange={setValue}
              buttons={[
                {
                  value: 'walk',
                  label: 'Walking',
                },
                {
                  value: 'train',
                  label: 'Transit',
                },
                {
                  value: 'drive',
                  label: 'Driving',
                },
              ]}>
    </SegmentedButtons>
          </SafeAreaView>
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library for Segment buttons in React native if react-native-paper **segment buttons** are not working
[Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-segmented-control-tab)

Comment: but what is the issue in react-native-paper? can't we solve it?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set up icons https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/icons.html especially https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons because paper uses it.

Comment: I already set up icons and had used in other  components 
and for react-native-vector-icons again I setup all the things and used in other sections

Comment: @ABDULLAH can you share code for all your component where you use `SegmentedButtons `

Comment: well I am using segmentButtons for the first time in my project and this happen

Answer (score 0):

Try move the react-native-paper from package.json and install it again .

Comment: I have already solve the issue by update the version of react-native-paper